# Bash expansion of ${@} as command

Tags: bash, shell-script, brace-expansion

I have a parent script

```
while read cmd 
do
  nohup ./script ${cmd[@]} &>> log &
done < ~/list
```

that executes this child script

```
while true
do 
  eval "${CMD[@]}"
  #${CMD[@]}
  #./panic
done
```

with this list of commands

```
node ~/www/splash/app.js
node ~/www/splash-two/app.js
```

When the child script calls `eval ${CMD[@]}` it executes the way I expect running that command with no complaints but when I try to remove the eval and run the command using `${CMD[@]}` it throws the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/rumplefraggle/SYS/RABBOT/~/www/splash/app.js'
```

Now I thought possibly this had something to do with the node command so I tried to execute 

`ls ~`

as the command and it throws the error that `~` can not be found.

Echoing `${@}` and not running it expands as I would expect it to.

Also manually inserting the command into the child script also works as expected

I don't understand why `eval` works and simply running the command using `${@}` does not. What is causing `${@}` to not expand the `~`?

Why is node appending the directory name to the command when `${@}` is used?

Comment: by the way: `read cmd`  reads an entire line as a single string, and assigns that string to `cmd`. So it makes little sense to use `${cmd[@]}`; `cmd` is not an array, so you might as well just use `$cmd`. If you want `read` to read into an array, use `read -a`. Also, you almost always want `read -r`. `help read` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of tilde expansion. The eval expands the tilde, which is replaced with the full path to the home directory. Without it, the command gets a literal tilde passed, and tries to use a relative path (that doesn't exist).

```
$ echo ~
/home/chris
$ echo "~" 
~
$ eval 'echo ~' 
/home/chris
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `eval 'echo ~'` or `eval "echo ~"`? Or even `eval echo "~"`? As typed, it will produce output `~`

Comment: I see and the error is reporting the full path! Its not actually the command being executed just an artifact in the error report. I need to dig more into the expansion and why it expands in eval an not on the path

Comment: @rici Thanks, my bad, I was typing this out from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes: `"${cmd[@]}"`

Without the quotes, all the elements of the array are smushed up into a single string. With quotes, each element will be properly handled individually.

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

> If the *subscript* is `‘@’` or `‘*’`, the word expands to all members of the array *name*. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, *[...]* `${name[@]}` expands each element of name to a separate word.

Comment: Correct, but that's not what the question is about.